# What is the exhaustive list of categories and properties that ImageIdentify can output?

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking for a complete list of `ImageIdentify`'s outputs.

I'm seeing entities like the one below, so I'm wondering what all possible classes are if they have some special name scheme:

[image]

and

Comment: Looking here, there are at least 10,000 of them. " - identify what an image is of (out of 10,000+ objects)" https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageProcessing.html

Comment: @blochwave There are obviously much more than that - there are 117,802 labels in EntityList["Concept"] but I can't tell if ImageIdentity can classify all of those or more....

Comment: What's interesting about the "Neat Example" here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageIdentify.html is the identification of "Berlin" as a likely ID. Alas I don't have 10.1 yet to investigate.